# Do you have to install Python somehow in order to run a script in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: python, azure-data-factory

Because all documentation that I find for how to run a Python script don't talk about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF doesnt provide a direct platform to execute Python scripts.
You can leverage Azure functions, Azure batch ,Azure automation or Azure databricks with Python via ADF